# git commits appear together when pulling fork to master

Tags: git, github

I have a forked repo of a main repo and
I am only adding staged files that I have changed to my commit then pushing
git push -U origin mybranchname -> to my fork

But when I compare changes on GitHub to make a pull request (to send changes to the main repo from my fork), my commits from different remote branches on my fork which I have pushed to show up together and its trying to pull them all over to the master repo at once

But I only want to pull changes from the remote branch(the one I pushed to) to the remote master I have forked from

I am wondering what the best way is to get around this, I have local changes I don’t want to lose, should I put those files aside somewhere else, rebase my fork to whatever state the origin/master is then pull down to my local, checkout a new branch then add the files back and push it again?

I’m asking because I tried this previously and I’m unfortunately still seeing the same issue and I’m not too sure what I’m doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

A [`git push -u`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--u) (`-U` does not exist) is only to set the current pushed branch as tracking the remote one.

Adding only your changes would be [`git add -u`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--u), then commit and push.

In your case, make sure to do a git rebase on top of the target branch (the one from the original repository)

```
cd /path/to/local/clone/of/fork
git remote add upstream /url/original/repository
git fetch upstream
git switch mybranchname
git rebase upstream/main # assuming this is the target branch
# make sure only your commits are replayed there
git push -f
# your PR is updated, and will show only mybranchname commits.
```